# Merging column values from two rows when values match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am having a problem with excel, hopefully someone here can offer some good advice. I have attached a link to the screenshot of my data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdlijp43kqga27j/Excelproblem.jpg?dl=0

I am hoping to merge cells from the 'Total Net Asset value' column when the 'date' and 'fund no.' are matching. For example, row 2 and row 26 have matching values in B and M columns. Therefore in this case I would like to add C2 and C26 together. Any ideas?

Many thanks, Al

Comment: your attached print screen is such poor quality, it is of no use. Use the Built-in image attachment options when writing questions. Also: while I think I worked out what you want to do, you haven't specified what the desired output is. where do you want to store the output of C2+C26 ? show us the data, as well as a "desired output" table...

Comment: I had to download a local copy of the image to properly zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this into K2 and fill for the whole column.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,B2,M:M,M2)
```

You are summing values in C where dates(B) match B2 AND fund number(M) match M2.